# Is it possible to only enable select input after checking radio button WITH only html or css?

Tags: html, css

As the title stated above, I'm just wondering if it is possible to enable a select tag only after checking radio button using only HTML and CSS?

For example: after selecting the radio button, then i will be able to access and click on the select box. [image: select + radio button]

Comment: Is a script on the html valid ?

Comment: im sorry i cant really understand what you mean

Comment: You can make it dissapear and appear , But not disable it

Comment: I believe you mean checkbox and not radio button, second I mean to that you can run an inline script from the html with an onclick attribute but I'm guessing you have a JS disabled / not permitted in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable without Javascript , But you sure can Hide/Show it using HTML, CSS.

Here is the sample :

HTML

```
 <input type="radio" name="1" id="radio">
    <select name="" id="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
```

CSS

```
#select{
      display: none;
    }
    #radio:checked ~ #select{
      display: inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pure CSS or HTML its not possible, you could only be able to set your select's display to none and show it when radio button gets focus , otherwhise you have to do it with JS, Also to prevent showing by mistake by hovering to other radio buttons, you have to assign a unique ID to the radio button and select.

Comment: so what you are saying is with HTML and CSS, i can make select disappear and make it appear when i select a radio button?

Comment: Question, doesn't it mean that when a the user blur from the the other input the selected will disappear?

Comment: yes, you can only show or not show the select , you could assign an ID for each to make them show or hide uniqly not by mistake made by focusing on other inputs

Answer (score 1):

**Second Solution**

As disabling is not possible without JavaScript, You can use this small trick that will act as a disabled property: `pointer-events: none;`

Even tho I don't recommend this, But it's still a good hack

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="1" id="radio">
    <select name="" id="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
  </select>
```

CSS

```
   #select{
      pointer-events: none;
    }
    #radio:checked ~ #select{
      pointer-events: all;
    }
```